# How to change the total coin supply in monero?

Tags: blockchain, block-reward, altcoin

How to decrease coin supply in monero ? I know it uses:

```
#define MONEY_SUPPLY      ((uint64_t)(-1)) // =18446744073709551616
```

but how make it 9223372036854775808 or lower ?

at int's it posible change to 8 16 32 bit's

```
2^2 = 4
2^4 = 16
2^8 = 256
2^16 = 65536
2^32 = 4294967296
2^64 = 18446744073709551616
```

How to use different values ?

Answer (score 2):

This does not control the money supply, contrary to what you might expect. If you want to cap it, you need to change get_block_reward (in src/cryptonote_basic/cryptonote_basic_impl.cpp) and stop emission when your chosen amount of coins is reached.